# How do I change the route of an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have a typical ASP.NET MVC controller, but I just want to change its route. The default route now is:

```
Blog/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

I want to change the route of a specific controller to

```
Blog/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

I tried to achieve this by adding the **Route**, **RouteArea** and **RoutePrefix** attributes to the controller but without any success.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which route is registered first?

Answer (score 1):

Add this route prior to the default

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BlogAdmin",
                url: "Blog/Admin/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "YourSpecificControllerName", action = "Index or other default action name", id= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Since this is for a specific you don't need `{controller}` part in your url. If you still want to specify it change the `url` argument to `"Blog/Admin/YourSpecificControllerName/{action}/{id}`" where `YourSpecificControllerName` is the name of your controller.
Also since the order of rote registration matters make sure that this route registered prior to the the default one